# SQL Select a value that is +1 another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database where student grade data are entered with the accompanying term. Similar to the below.

| STUDENT_ID | attempt_credits | REPORTING_TERM | STUDENT_START_TERM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | FA2020 | FA2020 |
| 1 | 4 | FA2020 | FA2020 |
| 1 | 3 | SP2021 | FA2020 |
| 1 | 3 | SP2021 | FA2020 |
| 2 | 3 | SP2021 | SP2021 |
| 2 | 4 | FA2021 | SP2021 |
| 2 | 3 | SP2022 | SP2021 |
| 2 | 3 | SP2022 | SP2021 |

I'm trying to pull the sum of attempted credits per term. When I need to grab the first term, I can simply specify in the WHERE clause that STUDENT_START_TERM = REPORTING_TERM.

But I'm also wanting to grab the sum of attempted credits in the second term. For example, for a student who started in FA2020, I want the spring term (SP2021) credits. One way I'm trying this is to

```
SELECT TOP 1 SUM(attempt_credits)
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE REPORTING_TERM LIKE 'SP%'
ORDER BY REPORTING_TERM
```

The challenge here is when a student starts in the spring, there's a possibility we may just want the first spring term after their first fall term. So for a student who started in SP2021 their progression would be SP2021 -> FA2021 -> SP2022. In this case, I'd like to grab just the SP2022 credits. Is something like the following possible:

```
SELECT SUM(attempt_credits)
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE REPORTING_TERM LIKE 'SP%' AND (LEFT(STUDENT_START_TERM, 4) + 1)
```

The idea of the above is to grab the sum of attempted credits where the reporting term starts with SP AND the last four is equal to one plus the STUDENT_START_TERM.

In other words, is there a way to pull the value of a column that is based on adding a total to another column?

Sidenote: I know I oversimplified the queries and am missing the GROUP BY clauses for the aggregation.

Edit: I want to stress that I don't disagree with the comments about normalization. I just want to add that joined as a data analyst for this team around 6 months ago and the database was well established well before my arrival. I'm kind of forced to work with what I'm given at this time. It sucks.

Comment: Your task would be much easier if your data were properly normalised; your data includes two separate entities <sp> / <fa> and a <year> - if these were separate columns for term/year life would be easier.

Comment: There are multiple levels of database design issues here. Normalization is important!!! You probably want at least three or four tables here. A SchoolYear table, then a table with terms and a foreign key to SchoolYear, don't forget there may be summer terms as well. Also in your data you have duplicate rows. This indicates you probably don't have a primary key on this table. The column attempt_credits also indicates you are storing aggregate values instead of enrollment in another table and calculating hours based on enrollment.

Comment: I want to stress that I don't disagree with the comments about normalization. I just want to add that joined as a data analyst for this team around 6 months ago and the database was well established well before my arrival. I'm kind of forced to work with what I'm given at this time. It sucks.

Comment: No one is pointing any fingers here it's simply free advice you can take back to your organisation; use the comments as a starting point to investigate and evaluate if they are valid (this is the internet after all and not everything is true) then document the issues & potential solutions and present it to your team / line manager.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the insight. I hope I didn't come off as defensive. Just wanted to add context. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's non-obvious to a computer that SP2021 is the term following FA2020. For example, the term after SP2021 is probably FA2021. The number doesn't just go up.

You *could* hard code some rules in to account for this, but probably somewhere you have a term definition table, and this table likely has a sequence number or start date. It will be better to JOIN to that table, so you can get a deterministic a result of what term is next.

Comment: Hmmm. You may be right here. I'll reach out to our database folks to see if such a table exists that I could reference. The challenge here I see is how to grab the second start term for a student when every cohort of students would have a different start term. So the sequencing wouldn't be the same for each student, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

We have all had to deal with less than ideal database structures from time to time. The point of the comments at least by me was in hopes that you can fix the design. That is BY FAR the best solution and would make these queries a lot easier. But sadly that kind of change is not always possible due to other constraints.

Staying within the confines of the denormalized structure you provided I think you could mangle this into something along these lines. The output here is mostly speculation because you didn't provide the desired output based on the sample data you provided.

```
create table #Students
(
    STUDENT_ID int
    , attempt_credits int
    , REPORTING_TERM char(6)
    , STUDENT_START_TERM char(6)
)
insert #Students values
(1, 3, 'FA2020', 'FA2020')
, (1, 4, 'FA2020', 'FA2020')
, (1, 3, 'SP2021', 'FA2020')
, (1, 3, 'SP2021', 'FA2020')
, (2, 3, 'SP2021', 'SP2021')
, (2, 4, 'FA2021', 'SP2021')
, (2, 3, 'SP2022', 'SP2021')
, (2, 3, 'SP2022', 'SP2021')
;

with SchoolYears as
(
    select STUDENT_ID
        , attempt_credits
        , REPORTING_TERM
        , STUDENT_START_TERM
        , SchoolYear = case when left(REPORTING_TERM, 2) = 'FA' then try_convert(int, right(REPORTING_TERM, 4)) else try_convert(int, right(REPORTING_TERM, 4)) - 1 end
        , SchoolYearName = case when left(REPORTING_TERM, 2) = 'FA' then right(REPORTING_TERM, 4) + '/' + convert(char(4), try_convert(int, right(REPORTING_TERM, 4)) + 1) 
                            else convert(char(4), try_convert(int, right(REPORTING_TERM, 4)) - 1) + '/' + convert(char(4), try_convert(int, right(REPORTING_TERM, 4))) 
                            end
    from #Students
)

select STUDENT_ID
    , AttemptedCredits = sum(attempt_credits)
    , SchoolYear
    , SchoolYearName = max(SchoolYearName)
from SchoolYears
group by STUDENT_ID
    , SchoolYear
order by STUDENT_ID
    , SchoolYear

drop table #Students
```